# Bypass bearer authentication in swagger in .Net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger-ui

I am using dotnet core we have configured swagger and all endpoints are running with bearer token authentication mechanism. We have one endpoint which it is should not authenticate means similar to anonymous call. I have decorated particular endpoint with [Anonymous] attribute but still it is expecting token gives as unauthorized how to bypass authentication mechanism in this case.

I am suspecting do we need change in startup class?

In Authentication middleware it tried implementing httpcontext.request.path.value == "/api/test" to ignore authenticate mechanism but the debugger is not hitting actual endpoint with parameters.

Comment: I think you just need to add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in Test Controller , not need to change others.